# Return a one to one relationship instance when database is many to many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship in the database that looks like
User -> user_companies -> company.

My issue is that in terms of our business logic this should be a one to one relationship however correcting this would take a lot of work.  In the pivot table there is only ever one entry of a User.

Currently on the user model I am doing this but it returns a model and not a relationship instance.

```
// returns relationship instance
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App/Company', 'user_companies');
}

// returns model
public function company()
{
    return $this->companies()->first();
}
```

Is it possible for me to mimic the behaviour of a one to one relationship whilst the database is set up as many to many?

UPDATE:

Laravel has now added a `HasOneThrough` relationship out of the box. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this, it's possible but you'd really have to dig into the core and build your own custom solution (Relationship Query Builder).

The first thing that comes to mind is a `hasOneThrough` relationship method. Unfortunately, this does not exist out of the box. My recommendation is to find a reliable package to accomplish this.

In fact, I was able to find this package: https://github.com/riesjart/relaquent

Otherwise, unless your DB Schema is a complete mess, adding a `company_id` to your `users` table and then writing the sql migration script would not be complicated in the least bit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll take a look. Unfortunately our application is large and old enough that we have a mix of query builder and eloquent so fixing the relationship will mean we will have to fix a lot of queries too!  hasOneThrough is a good idea, I'll dig into that.

Comment: @hdifen Would you look at that, Laravel _just_ implemented [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) functionality into Laravel 5.8

Comment: Yea haha. We've already put it into our code base :). I'll add an update to my question